# Using MSADO15.DLL and C++ with MinGW/GCC on Windows Vista

Tags: c++, gcc, ado, mingw, windows-vista

I have started initially with VC++ 2008 Express. I've noticed that GCC becomes kind of standard, so I am trying to make the right steps event from the beginning.

I have written a piece of code that connects to a [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) server via [ADO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET). On VC++, it's working like a charm by importing *MSADO15.dll*:

> **#import "msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")**

Because I am going to move from VC++ I was looking for an alternative (eventually multi-platform) IDE, so I stick (for this time) with [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) (*I'm using the last nightly build, SVN 6181*).

As the compiler, I choose to use GCC 3.4.5 (ported via [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) 5.1.6), under [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista).

I was trying to compile a simple "[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)" application with GCC that use/import the same msado15.dll (#import "c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")) and I was surprised to see a lot of compile-time errors.

I was expected that the #import compiler's directive  will generate a library from "msado15.dll", so it can link to it later (link-edit time or whatever). Instead it was trying to read it as a normal file (like a header file, if you like), because it was trying to interpret each line in the DLL (which has a MZ signature):

Example:

> Compiling: main.cpp 
> E:\MyPath\main.cpp:2:64: warning: extra tokens at end of #import directive 
> In file included from E:\MyPath\main.cpp:2: 
> c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll:1: error: stray '\144' in program 
> In file included from E:\MyPath\main.cpp:2: 
> c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll:1:4: warning: null character(s) ignored 
> c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll:1: error: stray '\3' in program 
> c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll:1:6: warning: null character(s) ignored 
> c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll:1: error: stray '\4' in program 
> ... 
> and so on.

Well, it is obvious that under this version of GCC the #import directive does not do the expected job (perhaps #import is not supported anymore by GCC), so how can I use the ADO to access SQL Server database on a C++ program compiled with GCC (v3.4.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC and MSVC use #import for different things.
In GCC, #import is an objective-c variant of #include that only includes the header file once.
In MSVC, #import triggers a Microsoft extension that builds a smart pointer implementation and header files from a COM type library.

In GCC you are going to have to import the COM object the old fashioned way. Find the existing interface definitions or use a tool like OleSpy to generate the definitions from the tlb.

Comment: Hi,
You are perfectly right, I already found this explanation on an article on Wikipedia. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The #import directive is not part of the standard C++ programming language. I don't know what (if anything) it does in GCC. The normal way to use a DLL is to include its header file(s) in your code and then link with its import library (the .LIB file). I've never programmed in ADO, but in ODBC you would

```
#include <sql.h>
```

and when compiling/linking

```
g++ mystuff.cpp -lodbc32
```

to get the import library.

Also, the version of the MinGW compiler you are using is very old. You can get a much more up-to-date one at http://tdragon.net/recentgcc.

Comment: Hi,
I tried to use  (just few minutes before you post your answer)  the sql.h header which is delivered with gcc. It look fine, I was little bit stubborn to stick with ADO just because I have already a small application which it is compiling just fine with MSVC++.

I have installed also the cygwin, and I have tried to generate the .a library from the msado15.dll file. The nm bash command just said "No symbols in msado15.dll" so it seems that the dll symbols have been stripped.

I saw the TDM-GCC web page, but I was discouraged to use it as it is "unofficial".

I will try it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Whats happens you try to import in very non-standard and MSVC specific way COM object...

AFAIK the support of COM with MSYS is far from begin perfect, search for: "component object model" and gcc in google.

I would suggest using [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) or library like [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net) for communication with MS-SQL. It is also cross platform `;-)`

Comment: What has MSYS got to do with it?

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply.
I was afraid that you will say this, Chris Becke and Neil Butterworth (see replies below) has pointed out the fundamental issue.
Thank you, I will give a try with FreeTDS as I am a bit comfortable with it from some previous PHP "projects".